# csv list index out of range - python

Tags: python, csv

I trying to get specific cell value in csv file and count number of the rows, but if I count the number before read the specific cell the error will come 
my code  is :

```
import os
import sys
import csv

with open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python test\update_test\datalog.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    data= csv.reader(csvfile)
    row_count=sum(1 for row in data)
    data=list(data)
    text=data[0][0]
    print(text)

    print row_count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just read from a file twice. `sum(1 for row in data)` already read all the data, so `data = list(data)` is an empty list, because the file pointer is at the end of the file and won't return more data unless you rewind the file to the start.

You don't even need to use the `sum()` call, remove it. You can get the same count with `len(data)` after you used `list()` on it:

```
with open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python test\update_test\datalog.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    data= csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = list(data)
    text = data[0][0]
    print(text)
    print len(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer, is that anyway I can use to count the number of rows first then read the cell value? how to rewind the file ?? thanks

Comment: @panda001: why do you need to do that first? Reading the file data twice is *slow* and inefficient.

Comment: @panda001: `csvfile.seek(0)` would seek back to the start.

Comment: Thanks Martijin, I need do a for loop later to send the cell value to my database so I need to know how many data i have to send